# How to take the text entered into one input text - box and copy that text into a list on another html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to synchronize some data between two html files. In the other html I have text input boxes, where the user should enter some data. The entered data should then be copied automatically into another html file and use there as a list item.

Comment: Better you can do is store the input data into localStorage and fetch the data from local storage in the next page.